# Install apt-cacher on a non-Ubuntu server (router)

Tags: router, dd-wrt, apt-cacher

Is there a way to install apt-cacher on a non-Ubuntu server?

I'm using DD-WRT on my router and I thought it would be nice if the apt-cacher was there instead of on a PC which has to be powered on if I want the caching.

I'm open to any other ideas about how I can achieve it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided your router has enough storage (e.g. external USB HDD), it shouldn't be a problem if you're familiar with the command line.

Your router is most probably running either an ARM or a MIPS processor. The appropriate debs can be found in the [Debian repositories here](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt-cacher-ng/?C=M;O=D). You can't install them directly on the router, so extract with `dpkg-deb -x filename.deb destination-dir` first.

You can then try moving the extracted files to your router, and seeing if the binaries appear to work. If not, you can always (cross-)compile them from source. I don't see anything in `apt-cacher-ng` that should prevent it from working on a non-Debian-based system.

---

#### Alternative: Use the OpenWRT packages

There's also an `apt-cacher-ng` branch for OpenWRT on Github [here](https://github.com/unforgiven512/openwrt-packages), and it looks like it's being actively updated. DD-WRT runs on a superset of the hardware supported by OpenWRT, so it would almost certainly compile and work on your system. This may be the easier option.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I'll try the OpenWRT packages and let you know how it went.

Comment: About the debs in the Debian repositories, my router is a Cisco E3000 with a Broadcom BCM4718 @ 480 MHz; which one do I download?

Comment: @Yusuf : `armhf` should work on the BCM4718. Please accept as answer if this helped you out. Thanks!